# Typedef error in C++

Tags: c++, c, qt

I am trying to use a library from my Qt project that has both C and C++ variants.

if I include the C ".h" file, it seems like I can use that ok. However, to stick with the style of my C++ QT project, I wanted to use the ".hpp" C++ version.

I am getting an error in this block of code from one of the libraries header files:

```
#ifndef __SYS_SEMAPHORE_H__
#define __SYS_SEMAPHORE_H__ 
/**
 *  \file 
 *  \brief Include the right semaphore.
 *
 *  This file will auto-select the semaphore of choice,
 *  if one is to be defined.  
 *  \note We need to change the windows part to check _MT
 *  because that is how it determines reentrance!
 *
 */
#  if defined(_REENTRANT)

#    if defined(USE_NSPR_THREADS)
#        include "sys/SemaphoreNSPR.h"
namespace sys
{
typedef SemaphoreNSPR Semaphore;
}
// If they explicitly want posix
#    elif defined(__POSIX) && !defined(__APPLE_CC__)
#        include "sys/SemaphorePosix.h"
namespace sys
{
typedef SemaphorePosix Semaphore;
}
#    elif defined(WIN32)
#        include "sys/SemaphoreWin32.h"
namespace sys
{
typedef SemaphoreWin32 Semaphore;
}
#    elif defined(__sun) && !defined(__POSIX)
#        include "sys/SemaphoreSolaris.h"
namespace sys
{
typedef SemaphoreSolaris Semaphore;
}
#    elif defined(__sgi) && !defined(__POSIX)
#        include "sys/SemaphoreIrix.h"
namespace sys
{
typedef SemaphoreIrix Semaphore;
}
#    elif defined(__APPLE_CC__)
typedef int Semaphore;
#    else
#        include "sys/SemaphorePosix.h"
namespace sys
{
typedef SemaphorePosix Semaphore;
}
#    endif // Which thread package?

#  endif // Are we reentrant?

#endif // End of header
```

The line defining SemaphorePosix typedef is where the error is happening, but I am getting this similar error in compilation across a few different header files that are doing this same sort of conditional including/typedef'ing.

Just to be specific, the error on compilation is "'SemaphorePosix' does not name a type"

Also, sys/*.h should be able to be reached - I have in the include path the top level about the sys folder from the libraries include folder

Comment: Well, does sys/SemaphorePosix.h define the SemaphorePosix type?

Comment: (not relevant to the problem at hand, but still important): Your code is technically undefined behavior: any identifier/macro starting with double underscore or underscore and capitalized letter is reserved by the implementation. Get rid of those underscores in your include guards!

Comment: @rubenvb it is not my library - it is the NITRO nitf library

Comment: It is tagged C because the C implementation of this library works correctly. Something is different when I try to switch to the C++ lib, and I am looking to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `::SemaphorePosix`? Or maybe this type is defined inside another namespace.